# i try to understand the js of the familyecho website, but i didn't find the code which should be here

Tags: javascript, family-tree

At familyecho website, when you click me box, there must be a click trigger, i try to find the function, but i didn't find it anywhere,can somebody tell me where it is,and it will be better to tell me how to find it out.
http://www.familyecho.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the "tree.js" file. Find the TCT function and roll over it through the functions ESP, EHW and SS, which hides the popup bar above using the GE function.

Comment: it seems right,can you tell me how you find this.in fact,i still don't understand why trigger that function

Comment: You need to:
1. Find the event listeners, that listen to events you need. You were talking about click, so those are: click, mousedown.
2. Find all the functions that are attached to these events.
3. Put some breakpoints.
4. Click.
5. F11 if you are working from chrome.

Comment: thanks a lot, sometimes i do that and it show the js of chrome extention, f11 and at the end it will not show the website's js.

Comment: for example ,when i start to listen the event, and i click the cross to close the tip window when first loaded, it will show the chrome extention js. i don't know the reason, and it showed not just once i debugged js in the past

Comment: You need to learn to work with chrome js debugger. Google it around.